# How to change VisualState via ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visualstates

I know this **Question** is similar to many. Anyway, I don't understand.

I have a several **VisualStates** (more than 2, thats why **DataStateBehavior** is not my solution). And I have ViewModel, which have **enum** property **CurrentState**. Every enum value represents to one state, also may be several enum values represents to one states, doesn't metter. I want **VisualState** changed when the **CurrentState** changed (thought, that immediately appears  in my mind : **Binding was created exactly for this case!**)

Can I bind **CurrentState** with view **VisualState** (xaml-only solution), to get the behavior described above?

If yes, how can I do it?

If no, how should I use **VisualStateManager.GoToState()** method in my **ViewModel**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't use VisualStateManager.GoToState in the ViewModel for a number of reasons, the biggest being you have to pass in the control whose visual state you're going to change.  Passing UI controls up to your viewmodel goes against the whole MVVM approach.

My suggestion is to use (for Windows 8 Store) [Winrt Behaviours](http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/) or to use the Blend system.windows.interactivity.dll (for same functionality) to take a VisualState name from a viewmodel and update an object.  The code would look something like this:

ViewModel:

```
public string State{
    get{_stateName;}
    set{_stateName=value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("State");
}
```

View:

```
<Grid>
    <I:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:VisualStateSettingBehavior StateToSet="{Binding State}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

Behavior:

```
public class VisualStateSettingBehavior:Behavior<Control>
{

    StateToSet{
               get{GetValue(StateProperty) as string;}
               set{SetValue{StateProperty,value);
                    LoadState();}
}
private void LoadState()
{
VisualStateManager.GoToState(AssociatedObject,StateToSet,true);
}
}
```

What the behaviour is doing is connecting up to the control and allowing you, in a programmatic way, to extend its functionality.  This approach allows you to keep the ViewModel separate from your View.

Comment: What namespace do you use for "b" to get the VisualStateSettingBehavior?

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to note a solution similar to @FasterSolutions', using built-in components of the Blend SDK.

Set a [`PropertyChangedTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.propertychangedtrigger_members%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) on the view-model's "CurrentState" property, and add a [`GoToStateAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.gotostateaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) to change the visual state:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Inte‌​ractivity"  
    xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microso‌ft.Expression.Interactions">
    <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentState}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="{Binding CurrentState}" />
    </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: for those who couldn't find e & ei, 
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"

Comment: @ay89 thanks, added above also.

Comment: These xmlns's work better in VS2015: `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"`