# How to control View VisualState through ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

**The question is:** How to get/set the `VisualState` of a `Control` (with more than two Visual States) on the `View` through my `ViewModel` in MVVM pattern (with zero-view-code-behind)?

I've seen similar questions who's answers didn't work for me:

- [Binding [VisualStateManager] view state to a MVVM viewmodel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002046/binding-visualstatemanager-view-state-to-a-mvvm-viewmodel)
- [How to change VisualState via ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190058/how-to-change-visualstate-via-viewmodel)

**Note:** *below I'll be explaining what was wrong with the answers in the mentioned questions. If you know a better approach, you can dismiss reading the rest of this question.*

As for the first question, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6002107/3602352)'s approach doesn't work for me. Once I type the mentioned XAML code

```
<Window .. xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mynamespace" ..>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
             local:StateHelper.State="{Binding Path=State, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Window>
```

It shows a design-time error that says: `The attachable property 'State' was not found in type 'StateHelper'.`, I tried to get over this by renaming `StateHelper.StateProperty` to `StateHelper.State`, ending up with two errors..
1: `The attachable property 'State' was not found in type 'StateHelper'.` and 
2: `The local property "State" can only be applied to types that are derived from "StateHelper".`

As for the second question, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12816035/3602352)'s approach doesn't work for me. After fixing `VisualStateSettingBehavior`'s syntax errors to be:

```
public class VisualStateSettingBehavior : Behavior<Control>
{

    private string sts;
    public string StateToSet
    {
        get { return sts; }
        set
        {
            sts = value;
            LoadState();
        }
    }

    void LoadState()
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(AssociatedObject, sts, false);
    }
}
```

I got a design-time error on the line

```
    <local:VisualStateSettingBehavior StateToSet="{Binding State}"/>
```

that says: `A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'StateToSet' property of type 'VisualStateSettingBehavior'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.`

I tried to merge the two solutions by making `VisualStateSettingBehavior.StateToSet` a dependency property, but I got other design-time errors in the `View`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, I could solve this. The solution was similar to the [first question's best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6002107/3602352). I found out that in my case there are some constraints on the `View.xaml` to use an attached property:

1. It has to be registered via `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached`.
2. It has to be **static**.
3. It must has a property instance (getter/setter).

I got through that with [this](http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.com.eg/2013/11/binding-visual-state-manager-to-view.html) coding-style in mind, and the final approach was:

**`VisualStateApplier`**:

```
public class VisualStateApplier
{

    public static string GetVisualState(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return target.GetValue(VisualStateProperty) as string;
    }
    public static void SetVisualState(DependencyObject target, string value)
    {
        target.SetValue(VisualStateProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VisualState", typeof(string), typeof(VisualStateApplier), new PropertyMetadata(VisualStatePropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void VisualStatePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToElementState((FrameworkElement)target, args.NewValue as string, true); // <- for UIElements, OR:
        //VisualStateManager.GoToState((FrameworkElement)target, args.NewValue as string, true); // <- for Controls
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
<!--A property inside the object that owns the states.-->
<local:VisualStateApplier.VisualState>
    <Binding Path="State"/>
</local:VisualStateApplier.VisualState>
```

**ViewModel**:

```
private string _state;
public string State
{
    get { return _state; }
    set
    {
        _state = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("State");
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess VisualStateApplier should inherit DependencyObject, right?